# How do I open a new window with POST data from a Gridview's onRowDataBound event, that must pass values from the other cells?

Tags: javascript, post, gridview, new-window

Okay the question is not exactly straightforward: let me explain.

I have a gridview, that I have hooked up to a datasource and all is peachy. I need to open a more detailed page for each row, so what would be the best way to do this? Currently I have something like this in the onRowDataBound function:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    try
        e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "<input type='image' src='images/more.png' width='20' alt='More...' onClick='test(\"" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "\");' />";
```

The test function would take the parameter, plus use some values of some controls on the current page to cause a new window to open with data POSTed to it. Is this possible? Currently my test function doesn't do much:

```
function test() {
    var argv = test.arguments;
    window.open('Details.aspx', 'more', 'width=300,height=200,resizable=yes,toolbar=no');
}
```

I'd like it to open Details.aspx with argv data POSTed to it. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to post data to server

1) Either put your data to url after "?" ( GET Request )
2) Either Put data in body of your request ( POST/PUT/DELETE Request )

In your case you only have first one as your just opening a link in new page.

So just your data in the query string like

http://yourdomain.com?a=val_a&b=val_b

Comment: Yes, that's the GET method. I would like to POST these variables. Is there no way to do that with my current setup? What would I have to change to POST the data, so no one can hack the URL?